# How can I get the NSManagedObjectID of an object directly after saving?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectid

How can I get the NSManagedObjectID of an object directly after saving?

I've tried using the `NSNotification` `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and getting the updated/inserted values and getting the object id from one (the only) managed object, but it's giving me "Unrecognized Selector"  when I try to grab the object id.

Can I even get the Object Id right after I save?

```
- (void)handleDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{

    NSDictionary *dict = [note userInfo];
    NSDictionary *updatedDict = [dict valueForKey:@"updated"];

    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", dict);
    NSLog(@"Updated Info: %@", updatedDict);

    NSManagedObject *core = [updatedDict valueForKey:@"entity"];

    NSManagedObjectID *objectId = [core objectID];
}
```

Comment: What you describe should work. Show some code for how you're trying to get the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a dictionary (`updatedDict`) when the returned data is a `NSSet`.
you might simply need to get it from the set collection it is in ...

```
NSSet* s = [dict valueForKey:@"updated"];
[s valueForKey:@"objectID"]
```

This will return a set of `NSManagedObjectID`s.
See [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on how to access objects.

Comment: Durf.  Okay, that makes sense, and it works like you say.  I should have been doing that from the beginning.  Do you happened to know why I can't get the object, then get the object id from that?

Comment: That exactly what you get. the set contains objects modified by the context. if you need to update another context though, you must do that in the other context "confinement" queue/thread and use object IDs.